# direccionar via get

Tags: php, post, get

Mi consulta es la siguiente, necesito direccionar a la misma pagina que esta creada en php con código html, y dentro de ella tengo un formulario de validación via post, cuando envio el post a la misma pagina que es index, valido los campos con php, entonces si existe un error hago un header location a la misma pagina donde envio via get un ?id=error, pero cuando se recarga la pagina por ende queda en el principio y necesito que baje hasta el id donde esta el formulario. como lo puedo hacer.

```
<?php 
if(empty($_POST['usuario']))
{
header("Location:index.php?id=contacto&num=1");
?>
?>
codigo principal.....
<!-- formulario de contacto 60 lineas mas abajo -->
<div id="contacto">
    <form method="POST">
<?php
if(num=="1")
{
   //muestro mensaje de error
}
?>
    <input name"usuario">
    <input type="submit">
```

Bueno esa es la idea, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza anclas junto a tus variables, añade al final del link **#contacto** (`id` del div que contiene el form):

**Solucion**

```
header("Location:index.php?id=contacto&num=1#contacto");
```

Ref: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f4/anclaje-variable-851568/

Answer (score 0):

bueno amigo puedes usar el siguiente código para mostrar el aviso en la página cuando se envié la petición por parte del formulario así :

> donde la variable de el get del header "num" es recibida por el $_GET del id y se muestra lo que necesitas

```
<?php if(empty($_POST['usuario'])) { header("Location:index.php?id=contacto&num=1");}?> codigo principal..... <!-- formulario de contacto 60 lineas mas abajo --> <div id="contacto"> <form method="POST"> <?php if($_GET["num"]=="1") { /*muestro mensaje de error*/ } ?> <input name"usuario"> <input type="submit">
```

**el otro más sencillo sería así :**

```
<?php if(empty($_POST['usuario'])) { $msg="<h3>este es un error</h3>";}?> codigo principal..... <!-- formulario de contacto 60 lineas mas abajo --> <div id="contacto"> <form method="POST"> <?php if(!empty($msg)) {echo $msg; /*muestro mensaje de error/* } ?> <input name"usuario"> <input type="submit">
```

> donde sele nuestra de manera sencilla el mensaje por medio de la variable "$msg" y se imprime cuando la misma está en true por decirlo así después de que sele activa.